# Django Conflicts Error When use ManyToManyField

Tags: django, postgresql

I have two model like given in bellow;

```
class userPages(models.Model):

    page_name=models.CharField(max_length=30)
    parent_id=models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.page_name


class userProfile(models.Model):

    user=models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name="profile")
    user_pages=models.ManyToManyField(userPages)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

When I want to add data like this;

```
.
.
.
 p1 = userPages(page_name='Login')
 p1.save()
 user_profile = userProfile(user=new_user)
 user_profile.save()
 user_profile.user_pages.add(p1)
```

I got "syntax error at or near "ON"".

```
LINE 1: ... ("userprofile_id", "userpages_id") VALUES (1, 1) ON CONFLIC...
```

Comment: post a full traceback, also which postgreSQL/Django version do you use

Comment: I use PostgreSQL 9.2.24.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming you use PostgreSQL version lower than 9.5  which does not have ON CONFLICT syntax on INSERT query ( [synopsis](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/sql-insert.html) ). Django ORM does not support following version and it is [documented](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/databases/#postgresql-notes)

> Django supports PostgreSQL 9.5 and higher. psycopg2 2.5.4 or higher is
> required, though the latest release is recommended.

You should upgrade PostgreSQL to at least 9.5 while long term support would likely require newer version

Comment: I use PostgreSQL 9.2.24. Isn't there any way I can fix the problem without upgrading my postgre version, at least for now.

Comment: no, you could use old Django version 1.10 but that would be bad from security perspective